# "import-cypher" neo4j exporting to csv without quotes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, export-to-csv

My neo4j version is 2.1 and I am using neo4j-shell-tools_2.1.zip in order to export data to a csv file in neo4j shell.

In the csv output, I would like to data **without quotes** and the following command does not seem to work. Is the command only for 2.2 version?

```
import-cypher -d , -o test.csv  match (p:Product)-[s:RELATED_TO]-(q:Product) return toInt(p.Id), toInt(q.Id) limit 3
```

The output of the above command in the test.csv looks like below.

```
"toInt(p.Id)","toInt(q.Id)"
"11505932","5944562"
"9594143","5944562"
"9594203","5944562"
```

How can I output without quotes? Is it even possible?
Thank you.

Comment: Good question, not sure I implemented it. Could make sense for non-strings.

Comment: can you raise an issue on GH, also please upgrade to 2.2.5 (or 2.2.6 next week)

Comment: yes, will raise the issue on GH. Eventually I ended up using sed to remove all quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Please raise an issue on GitHub or send a PR.

It would make sense to not use quotes for non-strings.